# How to create lesson pages for each course option in an e learning website using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-bootstrap

On the **admin dashboard** of my elearning site , I have created a page to add and delete a list of courses.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Container, ListGroup, ListGroupItem, Button } from 'reactstrap';
import { CSSTransition, TransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group';
import {v1 as uuid} from 'uuid';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {getItems,deleteItem} from '../actions/itemActions';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';

class CourseList extends Component{

    componentDidMount(){   //lifecycle method of react ; to be run when api request or calling an action
        this.props.getItems();
    }

onDeleteClick = id =>{
    this.props.deleteItem(id);
};

    render(){
        const { items } = this.props.item;

        return(
            <Container>
                <ListGroup>
                    <TransitionGroup className="courses-app">
                        {items.map(({id,name}) => (
                            <CSSTransition key={id} timeout={500} classNames="fade">
                                <ListGroupItem>

                                    <Button
                                    className="remove-btn"
                                    color="danger"
                                    size="lg"
                                    onClick={this.onDeleteClick.bind(this,id)}>
                                        &times;
                                    </Button>
                                    {name}<Link to={`/courses/${id}`}>{items.name} Lesson Page</Link>
                                </ListGroupItem>

                            </CSSTransition>
                        ))}
                    </TransitionGroup>
                </ListGroup>
            </Container>
        );
    }

}

CourseList.propTypes = {
    getItems: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    item: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = (state)=>({
    item: state.item
});


export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getItems,deleteItem})(CourseList);
```

This code is responsible for creation of each item( phy,chem) in the course page as shown in the following image:
[course list item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNYPL.png)

All I want is to add lessons for each course.

So when I add a new course(eg:maths) and click on it , it takes me to a new page where I can add lessons for it(eg:algebra, geometry). Refer to the following image:[lessons for each course](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVUkP.png)

I am using Redux and the itemReducer file associated with the Redux store is :

```
import {v1 as uuid} from 'uuid';
import {GET_ITEMS, ADD_ITEM, DELETE_ITEM} from '../actions/types';

const initialState={
    items:[
        { id: uuid() ,name:'Maths'},
        { id: uuid() ,name:'Physics'},
        { id: uuid() ,name:'Chemistry'}
    ]
}

export default function(state=initialState,action)
{
    switch(action.type)
    {
        case GET_ITEMS:
            return{
                ...state
            };
        case DELETE_ITEM:
            return{
                ...state,
                items: state.items.filter(item=>item.id!==action.payload)
            };
        case ADD_ITEM:
            return{
                ...state,
                items: [action.payload, ...state.items]   //spread operator:cuz we can't mutate the state, so we make a copy of it using this operator
            };
        default:
                return state;
    }

}
```

**Basically, I want to add child categories(on a new page) for each parent category added.**

Comment: Sorry there is quite a bit going on here. Are you trying to create a `Lessons` component for every item in `LessonList`?

Comment: I am trying to create a lesson page for every courselist item  For example  there are 3 course list item maths physics chem so each courselist item has its own lesson page which contains lesson1 lesson2...... Here maths physics chem are course list items inside the course page and lesson1 lesson2  lesson3 are lessonlist items in the lesson page

Comment: I agree with the first comment that there is a lot going on here, can you remove the clutter and specifically ask what are you looking for, however by what I can understand so far, you can use redux store to connect to the courseId/subjectId and fetch the relevant lessons of the course from your api from LessonList component, I don't know if it makes sense to you but I am answering based on what I understood the question which again I am afraid to read completely due to it being extremely long.